# access value from dict stored in python df

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Hi I want to access a value from a dictionary stored in a dataframe column and export it to a list.

I can do it by splitting it as a string, like this

```
# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[{'word' : '3'}, {'word':'1'}, {'word':'0'}], 'b':['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']})

# get the number value as a string 
idx = df['a'].astype(str).str[10].to_list()
```

but i thought it might be nicer to treat it as an actual dictionary and access via the dictionary item. However when I create the list via df['a'].items() the list stores the number inside a dict_values(['x']) string which I dont want to have, I just want [3,1,0].

```
# get the number value as a dictionary item 
[i[1].values() for i in df['a'].items()]
```

all suggestions welcome. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.get` to extract values from an `object` column with dictionaries in it.

```
df['idx'] = df['a'].str.get('word')

indices = df['idx'].to_list()
```

Comment: Or `df['a'].str['word']`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to convert the column to a list, cast it to a DataFrame constructor. This creates a DataFrame where the columns correspond to dictionary keys and values correspond to dict values. Then simply select the relevant column/key and convert the values to list:

```
idx = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].tolist())['word'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['3', '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi, you could just use a join**:

```
listElement = [''.join(i[1].values()) for i in df['a'].items()]
```

**Output:**

```
['3', '1', '0']
```